# How do i convert an image between PIL and cv2 without needless saving/loading (Python 3.6.3)

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

Python 3.6.3

How do i do the following without saving and loading the picture over and over again, is there a way to convert the image between the two formats? (Allowing me to only load the picture once at the beginning and save once at the end.)

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\programs\pic.jpg')
#modify picture using PIL functions
img.save(r'C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\programs\pic.jpg')

img = cv2.imread("pic.jpg")
#modify picture using cv2 functions
cv2.imwrite("pic.jpg", img)

img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\programs\pic.jpg')
#modify picture using PIL functions
img.save(r'C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\programs\pic.jpg)')
```

Comment: I don't use cv2, but doesn't `cv2.imread` just return a Numpy array? You can convert a Numpy array to a PIL image using `Image.fromarray` and you can convert a PIL image to a Numpy array with `np.asarray(img)`. However, PIL use RGB order and cv2 uses BGR order, but that's easy enough to handle with Numpy operations.

Comment: The linked answer uses `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` to reverse the color channel order. To do it in Numpy you can do [`np.flip(img, axis=-1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) which creates a new view of the `img` array, so it's very fast.

Comment: oh sorry i searched but didnt find that, should i delete this post since its a duplicate? thanks a tonne

Comment: There's no need to delete this question: it might help a future reader to find the linked question.